# .vcd and .saif files

Tags: verilog, vivado, vivado-hls

I am using vivado 2017.1 and my purpose is to compute power consumption of an FIR filter. I am coding in verilog in xilinx ISE and importing those files in vivado. I have generated .vcd and .saif files by using these commands in testbench.

```
    initial begin
    $dumpfile("test.vcd");
    $dumpvars(1, testbench_FIR.uut);
    end
```

My question is, how to use both .vcd and .saif file for this purpose. I know the difference between these two. I can upload .saif file in "switching" tab of power report but i couldn't find any other place where i can upload my .vcd file. I have seen many tutorials and read vivado suit guidelines as well. Am i doing something wrong? Is only .saif file necessary for power report? A document says that they have dynamic power 0.727W for FIR filter but for same code and same filter design, i have 25.09W as dynamic power consumption. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

.vcd and .saif can be used interchangeably, for power consumption estimates there should be no need to provide both. Not sure why there is such big discrepancy between reference design and Your design, is it the same RTL code for both ? Are You sure both were running at the same fMAX ? Very important thing is to double check that .vcd/.saif covered 100% switching activity while tool read it but guess You know about it already.

I suggest to open ticket against xilinx ISE and discuss this matter with their representative.